# Multiple sslhandshakeexceptions with connection factory (websphere 8.5.5.20)

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I have a Java 8 application running on WebSphere 8.5.5.20 with configured connection factory. Recently, I started getting errors stating that the connection factory could not connect to the queue manager. In the system out log, I can see multiple SSLHandshakeExceptions with different descriptions, such as 'unrecognized SSLv2Hello', 'plaintext connection', 'client request protocol TLSv1.1 not enabled or supported', and 'client supported protocol versions [TLSv1.3] are not accepted by server preferences'.

I have checked the configuration of the connection factory, and it has the correct SSL settings with protocol TLSv1.2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The last two error messages indicate that the client has been configured to require TLS 1.3, but the server does not support it. That doesn’t tend to just happen. It would suggest a change was made, I’d guess to the client (in the case WebSphere).